# Nav Bar Hidden on View Controller On Second and Subsequent Appearances

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a parent TableViewController and a child ViewController all within the context of a navigation controller.  What I want to happen is for the table view controller to NEVER show the nav bar, and for the view controller to ALWAYS show the nav bar. I hide and show the nav bar within the viewWillAppear func of each subclass, like this:

table view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true);
    navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden=true
}
```

view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

This works for the first navigation.  When I launch the app, the parent table view controller hides the nav bar, and when I select the first cell, the child view controller dutifully displays the nav bar.  However, when I touch 'Back' on the nav bar, and then select the cell again, the view controller is no longer displaying the nav bar.

Is there a better way to do this?

Update - as requested attaching screenshots of XIB and Storyboard.  Note that there is no XIB for the parent TableViewController.  I am not confident that these screenshot will provide much insight. Especially that of the storyboard.  Unfortunately, Xcode only has 2 zoom levels:
1. Too zoomed in to be useful
2. Too zoomed out to be useful
Nonetheless, here you have them:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard?

Comment: why are you hiding status bar every time in viewwillappear? also implement super.viewWillAppear(true); in second controller.

Comment: If you do not want the navigation bar to appear, why don't you present the TableViewController modally?

Comment: @DejanSkledar Actually, no, now that I think about it.  I am using story board for some aspects of this project but not for all.  The tableviewcontrollers are all programmatic, and the view controller has a xib, but is not attached to the storyboard...

Comment: @Gagan_iOS  The reason I ended up doing this is viewWillAppear is because when I set this in viewDidLoad I also had a very strange effect:  The TVC would load hiding the nav bar (expected) and the VC would then load showing the nav bar (expected) but when I hit Back, the TVC would then be showing the nav bar!!  Moving the hiding of the nav bar to viewWillAppear worked for the TVC.  Not sure why it is not working for the child VC.

Comment: @HermannKlecker  I added: self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen but this did not resolve this issue.  Is there a better way to present the modality of the TVC?

Comment: Changing the modalPresentationStyle does not do anything until you actually present it modally. Prgorammatically do that by `self.presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)` or in the story board you change the mode/type of the related segue.

Comment: As you told that you are using XIB as well as storyborad for UI preparation, I think you are getting mess between XIB & Storyboard. By the way add below code in AppDelegate.swift file not in ViewDidLoad


UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden=true


And If possible please attach your XIB & Storyboard screenshot.

Comment: @HermannKlecker The tableviewcontroller is the root controller of a navigation controller.  Also, I tried adding the line of code you suggested but got the error that a tableviewcontroller cannot be converted to a UIViewController which that function seems to want.

Answer (score 2):

That should work fine: When your ViewController will appear, the code should get executed every time. Try with an "print" to test if that happens.

First View Controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    print("viewWillLoad - Table View")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Second View Controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    print("viewWillLoad - Detail View")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Ill use that in some applications too.

Comment: I added the print statement to the viewWillAppear func of the child vc.  Interestingly, that func gets called every time, but the nav bar is hidden anyway on subsequent appearances.  Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide a screen of your Storyboard.

Comment: I have supplied the screen shot but I cannot imagine it would be useful.  Basically what I think I need to figure out is why the one line of code unhiding the nav bar is not being triggered in viewWillAppear, even though the print statement shows that that function is being hit.  Any thoughts?